# Count the number of distinct values in an MS Access Table in a chosen date

Tags: count

We use an MS Access split form for data entry, and on a daily basis, We enter about 600 boat movements. We work two 12-hour shifts per day, one from 06:00 to 18:00 and the other from 18:00 to 06:00 the next morning. We have about 200 boats, although not all of them move every day. One boat may make at least 10 to 15 movements every day. In my data entry form, I have two text boxes where I can record how many boats are moved throughout each shift. How can I reach my goal? I just started using MS Access. We greatly value the sensible advice you have provided.

I haven't tried anything so far